# how to prevent going back to home page after log out in php

Tags: authentication

these are codes of my login and log out. It works well in login bt not in log out. it goes back to home page after log out. plz help me with this

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == "yes") {
    echo "<script>window.location='ShowRecentVisit.php';</script>";
    exit();
}
?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
                window.location = "LoginPage.html";
            }
        </script>
        <nav class="materialize-red">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
                <ul style="margin-left:10%;" id="nav-mobile" class="center hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li class="waves-effect waves-ripple waves-light">
                        <a href="sass.html">Sass</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="waves-effect waves-ripple waves-light">
                        <a href="badges.html">Components</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="waves-effect waves-ripple waves-light">
                        <a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container z-depth-1">
            <form action="UserLogin.php" method="post">
                <table class="centered">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="userMail" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="password" name="userPass" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-ripple">
                            Login
                        </button></td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-ripple" id="btn1" onclick="test()">
                            Sign Up
                        </button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is login control page. login in is perfect.
//This is UserLogin.php

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Expires: Fri, 06 Jun 1975 15:10:00 GMT');
include ("dbConfig.php");
session_start();
$userMail = $_POST['userMail'];
$userPassword = $_POST['userPass'];
$userPassword = md5($userPassword);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE Usergmail = '$userMail';";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($row['1'] == $userPassword) {
    $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "yes";
    $_SESSION["save_url"] = $_POST['userMail'];
    header("location: ShowRecentVisit.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo "<script>window.location='http://www.youtube.com';</script>";

}
?>
```

in this portion. log out is ok. bt i can return to home page after log out. how can i solve it
// This is logout.php

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Expires: Fri, 06 Jun 1975 15:10:00 GMT');
session_start();

if (session_destroy()) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    header("location: LoginPage.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is LoginPage.php?

Comment: top most one is LoginPage.php Arthur Samarcos

Comment: ShowRecentVisit.php is what you call home page?

Comment: yes bro. that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got that right you need to implement an access control on ShowRecentVisit.php so that it checks if the user is authenticated.

You need to do this not only on this file, but on any other that you need to prevent guest (not authenticated) access.

Maybe put this code on the start of the file:

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]) || $_SESSION["logged_in"] != "yes") {
    echo "<script>window.location='GUEST_PAGE.php';</script>";
    exit();
}
```

You could create a file with this code and require it on the needed locations, so you can make it more easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks alot bro. i got this.